# Extract background-image from an HTML element in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to extract background-url from a div using Nokogiri but am not able parse background-url of it.

While Searching on StackOverflow I found this link
[Parsing: Can I pick up the URL of embedded CSS Background in Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153683/parsing-can-i-pick-up-the-url-of-embedded-css-background-in-nokogiri)
but the solution given there doesn't work.

Comment: add some html to see, what are you trying to parse

Comment: you can do regular expression to capture all the url as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri is not a web browser. It stands on top of libxml2 to provide fast and excellent parsing of XML and HTML, and manipulation and extraction of data from this.

It only deals with the HTML in a web page. It does not run any JavaScript. It does not apply CSS to the DOM. There is no way to use Nokogiri to find a CSS style applied to an element unless it is directly on the `style="..."` attribute on that element. (And even then you would need to use something else, like regex, to parse the CSS therein.)

You will want to use something else, like a headless browser controlled by Ruby, e.g. Watir or Selenium, if you want to process a web page and treat it like a web browser does.

Comment: Thanks for reply. yest I also find that it is not possible using nokogiri. I will look for an alternative solution for it.