# parse external css for background image urls of website

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I need to get all the background images from a given website URL in a Rails script

I have tried with Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) // url - will be any website
```

Here is the website HTML and CSS:

```
<h1 class="logo">
  <a href="/">Website Name</a>
</h1>

.logo {
  width: 193px;
  height: 73px;
  float: left;
  background: url(/themes/site_themes/tccc/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve logo background image URL from an external file.
We can retrieve inline style with Nokogiri, but I've been unable to find a solution for external style.

I want to get all background images from the provided website with any Web **scraper**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917542/extract-background-image-from-an-html-element-in-ruby?

Comment: You can't do this with Nokogiri. You need Watir or Selenium or some other Ruby-controlling a browser. See [the similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917542/extract-background-image-from-an-html-element-in-ruby) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.@orde its a similar kind of question with more elaboration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Phrogz after many try with Nokogiri, I came to one hack that we can get all stylesheet files and with the help of css_parser we can get the background image url, but iterating all stylesheets, can't be a good solution.I will look into a solution you provided, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Do Somethings like this to get an array of background-images with the name of the tag,class or id with which that image belongs.

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(open(path_to_html_file)
background_images = search_in_css(document.css('style'))
```

and create a private method that will process the styles and returns and 2D array with the tag,name or id and path to that image.

```
private
  def search_in_css(styles)
    background_images = Array.new
    if styles.count > 0
      styles.each do |style|
        style.children.each do |prop|
          string = prop.to_s.delete("\n").delete("\t").delete(' ').gsub('"', "'")
          each_klass = string.split("}")
          each_klass.each do |el|
            arr = el.split("{")
            klass_name = "css_" + arr[0]
            image_url = arr[1][/background-image\:url\((.*?)\)\;/m, 1].delete("'")
            background_images << [ klass_name, image_url ]
          end
        end
      end
    end

    return background_images.uniq
  end
```

This method will do through each line and only put the took the background-image property of css and append it to the array with the name of that class.